# Specified dependency definition runtimeSpecified dependency definition runtime(org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java-0.8.5) is invalid! Skipping

Tags: grails, dependencies

for ur note, am new to grails.
Am trying to use export plugin in my project. 
When am running my project am getting these dependency error as "Specified dependency definition runtime(org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java-0.8.5) is invalid! Skipping.."
Can anyone help me to get rid of this error plz?
And here is my domain class code:

class Book {
    String author
    String title
    }

And here is my controller code:

```
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
class BookController {
def exportService
def grailsApplication  //inject GrailsApplication
static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

def index() {
    redirect(action: "list", params: params)
}

def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
      if(!params.max) params.max = 10

    if(params?.format && params.format != "html"){
        response.contentType =      grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=books.${params.extension}")


        List fields = ["author", "title"]
        Map labels = ["author": "Author", "title": "Title"]


                    // Formatter closure
        def upperCase = { domain, value ->
            return value.toUpperCase()
        }

        Map formatters = [author: upperCase]        
        Map parameters = [title: "Cool books", "column.widths": [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]]

        exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream, Book.list(params), fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
    }
            [bookInstanceList: Book.list(params), bookInstanceTotal: Book.count()]
}

def create() {
    [bookInstance: new Book(params)]
}

def save() {
    def bookInstance = new Book(params)
    if (!bookInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [bookInstance: bookInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), bookInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: bookInstance.id)
}

def show(Long id) {
    def bookInstance = Book.get(id)
    if (!bookInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [bookInstance: bookInstance]
}

def edit(Long id) {
    def bookInstance = Book.get(id)
    if (!bookInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [bookInstance: bookInstance]
}

def update(Long id, Long version) {
    def bookInstance = Book.get(id)
    if (!bookInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    if (version != null) {
        if (bookInstance.version > version) {
            bookInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                      [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book')] as Object[],
                      "Another user has updated this Book while you were editing")
            render(view: "edit", model: [bookInstance: bookInstance])
            return
        }
    }

    bookInstance.properties = params

    if (!bookInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [bookInstance: bookInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), bookInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: bookInstance.id)
}

def delete(Long id) {
    def bookInstance = Book.get(id)
    if (!bookInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    try {
        bookInstance.delete(flush: true)
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book'), id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: id)
    }
}
```

}

Build Config :

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
// inherit Grails' default dependencies
inherits("global") {
    // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
    // excludes 'ehcache'
}
log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()

    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
```

mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
}

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    compile 'org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java-0.8.5'

    runtime 'org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java-0.8.5'

     // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
}

plugins {
    runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.2"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

    compile ':cache:1.0.1'

    compile ":export:1.6"
        }
```

}

List.gsp :

```
<%@ page import="com.awnsys.Book" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'book.label', default: 'Book')}" />
    <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    <r:require module="export"/>
    <export:resource />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#list-book" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
    <div class="nav" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
            <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="list-book" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
        <h1><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
        <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <g:sortableColumn property="author" title="${message(code: 'book.author.label', default: 'Author')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="title" title="${message(code: 'book.title.label', default: 'Title')}" />

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${bookInstanceList}" status="i" var="bookInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${bookInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "author")}</g:link></td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: bookInstance, field: "title")}</td>

                </tr>
            </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="pagination">
            <g:paginate total="${bookInstanceTotal}" />
        </div>
        <export:formats formats="['excel']" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the dependency code: 
It works correctly.

```
repositories {
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
    }

dependencies {
    runtime 'org.apache.odftoolkit:odfdom'
}
```

Comment: I also had this problem.  To elaborate on this answer, export 1.6 uses odfdom-java 0.8.5 but maven central only has releases 0.8.6 and 0.8.7.  That's understandable given their age (2010 and 2011).  The repository mentioned here also has 0.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency to your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
repositories {
    ...
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
}

dependencies { 
    ...
    compile 'org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java:0.8.5'
}
```

Comment: try removing "runtime 'org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java-0.8.5'" keep compile 'org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java-0.8.5'

Comment: same error! "Specified dependency definition compile(org.odftoolkit:odfdom-java-0.8.5) is invalid! Skipping.."